# Javascript createElement and appendchild in one step

Tags: javascript, appendchild, createelement

i want to create an element and then append this with other elements in one step.

```
var header = document.createElement("thead").appendChild(document.createElement("tr"));
```

Why this Code outputs the only TR and not Thead?

When i use this code then its correct (thead + tr are there)

```
var header = CH.createElement("thead");
    header.appendChild(CH.createElement("tr"));
```

Comment: The correct code you have is more readable than some "one-step" one liner monstrosity anyway

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem? If so, don't forget to tick the "accepted" checkmark. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Because [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.appendChild) returns *the appended child*...

```
var appendedChild = element.appendChild(child);
```

.. you can simply reference the child's [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.parentNode) like so ([sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ad3Tp/1)):

```
var header = document.createElement("thead")
    .appendChild(document.createElement("tr"))
    .parentNode; // the row's parentNode, i.e.: thead
```

Comment: ah okay, so i thought in jQuery... where a function returns this (reference to object)...

Answer (score 1):

@antisanity has a good solution. Another solution if your variable is pre-declared is to do this...

```
(header = document.createElement('thead'))
      .appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
```

This ensures that the assignment to `header` happens before the `.appendChild()`.